# Interaction with Docx file in IOS application (Modify, Add Comments)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to view a docx file in my app and the user can modify it, and add comment to a line like the image below.

Right now im using UIWebView to view it but cannot make a modification that way, is there a way to do this ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJKrS.png

Comment: It is not easy, you want to write Microsoft Word application for iOS. There are some libraries for manipulating docx file in pyhton or node. Maybe you can process your file in your server.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz thank you for the answer, I've been looking around to find a way and came across OpenXML SDK. Do you know how to implement it ? Or have a guide of some sort for this, since I can't seem to find a guide like that anywhere